# My output does not show the desired amount

Tags: c#

I am getting this error on my output. The code does not show any error on compiling.This is the error that was showing.

> Balance after Deposit:System.Action`1[System.Int32]
> Withdrawn :System.Action`1[System.Int32]

[image]
Here is my code:

```
    String accName;
    String acid;
    int balance;

    public Account() { }
    public Account(string accName, string acid, int balance)
    {
        this.accName = accName;
        this.acid = acid;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public void setAccName(String accName) { this.accName = accName; }
    public void setAcid(String acid) { this.acid = acid; }
    public void setBalance(int balance) { this.balance = balance; }   

    public String getAccName() {  return accName; }
    public String getAcid() {  return acid; }   
    public int getBalance() { return balance; }
    
    public void Deposit(int amount)
    {
        if (amount > 0) 
        {
            balance = balance + amount;
        }  
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insufficient Balance");
        }
    }
    public void Withdraw(int amount)
    {
        if (balance < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can Not Withdraw");
        }
        else if (amount > balance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can Not Withdraw");
        }
        else
        { 
            balance = balance - amount;
        }
    }
    public void ShowInfo () 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account Info .......");
        Console.WriteLine("Account Name:" + accName);
        Console.WriteLine("Acccount Id :" + acid);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Balance :"+balance);
        Console.WriteLine("Balance after Deposit:" + Deposit);
        Console.WriteLine("Withdrawn :" + Withdraw);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account InFormation.....");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Account Name :");
        String accNAme = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Account Id :");
        String accID = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Balance :");
        int balance = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Deposit Amount:");
        int Deposit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter withdraw amount:");
        int Witdraw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Account a1 = new Account();
        a1.setAccName(accNAme);
        a1.setAcid(accID);
        a1.setBalance(balance);
        a1.getAccName();
        a1.getAcid();   
        a1.getBalance();
        a1.ShowInfo();
    }
```

I want to put a amount of deposit and withdraw then Get the balance as output.Why is it showing this error.Its runs but there is an error.I think there is a problem with creating object.

Comment: This is C#, why have you tagged unrelated Java and C++?

Comment: You should definitly read about [properties in .net](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: `set*` and `get*` methods are so Java. You should try C# properties instead.

Comment: Can you fix your code so that I can run it?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the functions, but instead concatenating them onto the end of the string before printing it.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Balance after Deposit:" + Deposit);
Console.WriteLine("Withdrawn :" + Withdraw);
```

So both `Deposit` and `Withdraw` are being cast to "Deposit:System.Action`1[System.Int32]".

By the looks of it you are actually wanting to get the input variables from Main. Best way to do that is either store those values somewhere in the Account class, or pass those values into the ShowInfo function

```cs
    public void ShowInfo (int depositAmount, int withdrawAmount) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account Info .......");
        Console.WriteLine("Account Name:" + accName);
        Console.WriteLine("Acccount Id :" + acid);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Balance :"+balance);
        Console.WriteLine("Balance after Deposit:" + depositAmount);
        Console.WriteLine("Withdrawn :" + withdrawAmount);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account InFormation.....");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Account Name :");
        String accNAme = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Account Id :");
        String accID = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Balance :");
        int balance = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Deposit Amount:");
        int Deposit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter withdraw amount:");
        int Witdraw = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Account a1 = new Account();
        a1.setAccName(accNAme);
        a1.setAcid(accID);
        a1.setBalance(balance);
        a1.getAccName();
        a1.getAcid();   
        a1.getBalance();
        a1.ShowInfo(Deposit, Withdraw);
    }
```

Comment: `Deposit` and `Withdraw` are both `void` methods. They don't have a return value, so your answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity good catch I missed that. Will update my answer accordingly